# Finding symbols in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list e.g. `["1","2","n","5","n","x","0","v","-","a","l","4","1","v","m","z","o","5","%","d",";","a","m","6"]`
I want to print out the elements that are a letter or special symbol.
how do I do this?

Comment: `print(*[x for x in L if not x.isdigit()])` should work in this case

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken characters like ";" or "%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python comes with an `isnumeric()` method that returns true when a string is a number. In the case you listed you could try:

```
string_list = ["1","2","n","5","n","x","0","v","-","a","l","4","1","v","m","z","o","5","%","d",";","a","m","6"]
for value in string_list:
    if not value.isnumeric():
        print(value)
```

...which would output

```
n
n
x
v
-
a
l
v
m
z
o
%
d
;
a
m
```

Comment: ```if not value.isnumeric():``` would be more Pythonic.

Comment: True and that's good feedback. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isdigit()`. Like so:

```
some_str = "12a"

for i in some_str:
   print(i.isdigit())

# outputs
True
True
False
```

Comment: This is a good starting point but the question calls out that the value should be printed (not a boolean) and only when the value is not a number. You could still use isdigit but it would need to be in an if statement. The print would be print(i)